# Dual of a product of normed spaces is the product of the duals

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces. Consider $E^* \times F^*$ endowed with the norm $\|(v,f)\| = \|v\|+\|f\|$, and consider $J: (E \times F)^* \rightarrow E^* \times F^*$ defined by $g \mapsto (g_{|_{E \times 0}}, g_{|_{0 \times F}})$. I'm trying to prove that $J$ is a linear isometry. I've proved that it's a linear biyection, and that
$$ \| g\| \leq \| J(g)\|.$$

However, I couldn't prove the converse inequality. Could you give me a help?

Comment: What is the norm of $E^* \times F^*$?

Comment: @azif00 I've added that detail. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

It does matter how we define the norms in $E\times F$ and $E^*\times F^*$. The should be *conjugate norms*. For example, for $(x,y)\in E\times F$,
$$
\|(x,y)\|=\max\{\|x\|_E,\|y\|_F\},
$$
while
for $g\in (E\times F)^*$,
$$
\|g\|_*=\sup_{\|(x,y)\|=1}|g(x,y)|=\sup_{\|(x,y)\|=1}g(x,y).
$$
i.e., $\ell^\infty$ versus $\ell^1$. (Similarly, $\ell^2$ versus $\ell^2$.)

If $g\in (E\times F)^*$, define $g|_E(x)=g(x,0)$ and $g|_F(y)=g(0,y)$.

If $g\in (E\times F)^*$, then
$$
\|g\|_*=\sup_{\|(x,y)\|=1}|g(x,y)|=\sup_{\|(x,y)\|=1}|g(x,0)+g(0,y)|
\\ \le \sup_{\|(x,y)\|=1}||g(x,0)|+\sup_{\|(x,y)\|=1}|g(0,y)|
\\ \le \sup_{\|x\|_X=1}|g(x,0)|+\sup_{\|y\|_Y=1}|g(0,y)| \\=\|g|_E|\|_*+\|g|_F|\|_*
$$

On the other hand, for all
$x\in E$ and $y\in F$, with $\|x\|,\|y\|\le 1$, such that
$$
\|g\|_*\ge g(x,0)+g(0,y)=g|_E(x)+g|_F(y)
$$
and hence
$$
\|g\|_*\ge \sup_{\|x\|=1}g|_E(x)+\sup_{\|y\|=1}g|_F(y)=\|g|E\|_*+\|g|F\|_*.
$$